# angular2 html 5 audio player ontimeupdate event

Tags: javascript, html, audio, angular, html5-audio

I have a simple angular application that has an audio player integrated.

```
<audio id="passage-audio" class="passage" controls ontimeupdate="document.getElementById('tracktime').value = this.currentTime ;">
    <source src="Luke.2.1-Luke.2.20.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    <em class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> Your browser doesn't appear to support HTML5 Audio.</em>
</audio>
```

the audio player has an event called "ontimeupdate", this will update the time in the html element with the id "tracktime". This works fine.

What i would like to do is to use "ontimeupdate" to invoke a function in the controller. Right now it is not has access to the class.

```
<audio id="passage-audio" class="passage" controls (ontimeupdate)="updateTime()">...
</audio>
```

I there a way to accomplish this?

If i write an audio directive will i be able to access this event?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try `<audio ... (timeupdate)="updateTime()">`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want, but if it is to update you angular app at each timeupdate, you can accomplish this by calling `$scope.$apply()` and passing a $scope function.

Comment: This seems to be for Angular 1, but the question is regarding Angular 2

Comment: missed that one. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me

```
function onChangeAudio(event) {
   var duration = event.srcElement.duration;
   alert("call")
}


<audio controls class="w-100" id="audio"  (timeupdate)="onChangeAudio($event)">
    <source src="..." type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="..... " type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```